# Javascript: how to get mouse-selected element with getelementsbyclassname

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML Code:

```js
var dragItem = document.getElementsByClassName("dragElement");
var dropLoc = document.getElementById("dropLocation");

dragItem.ondragstart = function(evt) {
 evt.dataTransfer.setData('key', evt.target.id);
 console.log("its dragging....");
}

dropLoc.ondragover = function(evt) {
 console.log("its dragover....");
 evt.preventDefault();
}

dropLoc.ondrop = function(evt) {
 console.log("its dropped...."); 
 var dropItem = evt.dataTransfer.getData('key');
 evt.preventDefault();
 var myElement = document.getElementsByClassName(dropItem);
 var myNewElement = document.createElement('img');
 myNewElement.src = myElement.src;
 dropLoc.appendChild(myNewElement);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>Solitaire</title>
</head>
<body>
 <ul>
     <li><img src="1.png" class="dragElement"></li>
     <li><img src="2.png" class="dragElement"></li>
     <li><img src="3.png" class="dragElement"></li>
     <li><img src="4.png" class="dragElement"></li>
     <li><img src="5.png" class="dragElement"></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="dropLocation"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dragdropavatar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can i assign to dragItem (1st line of javascript file) the the img i have selected by the mouse to drag? With getelementsbyclassname i get all elements, and not only the one i selected, and the variable keeps empty.

Thank you.

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns nodeList,  you need to iterate the same and add event listeners individually to each item in node list

Comment: Try `evt.target`.